# Where to find the App Service Logs for a Http Trigger Function written in Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-powershell, azure-function-app

In Azure I create a Function App with Powershell Core Runtime stack:

[image: screenshot 1]

Then I add an Http Trigger with the following code:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request XXX."
```

Then I go to Code + Test, Test/Run and click the **Run** button.

In the **Output** field on the right side I see the HTTP response content.

But the **Logs** field at the bottom only shows

> Connecting to Application Insights...

[image: screenshot 2]

I have tried to navigating to the Logs in the left menu, but the **App Service logs** entry is disabled there:

> This feature is not available for Function apps. Please use Application Insights.

[image: screenshot 3]

So I try following the advice and got to the Application Insights, but can not find my trace there -

[image: screenshot 4]

Please help me to find the trace

> PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request XXX.

**UPDATE:**

I have followed the advice by Tony Ju (thanks!) and I can see some logs, but cannot find the trace line I am after yet:

[image: screenshot 4]

Comment: Will your function appear like `Connected`? On my side: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOtQs.png

Comment: No, the black Logs output at the bottom only shows "Connecting to Application Insights..." and that is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the logs under **Monitor**. Note that there will be 5 mins delay to display the logs. And it will only show the twenty most recent function invocation traces.

[image]

You can also find the logs in the application insights directly.

[image]

**Update:**

If you still can not find the logs there, you can try to restart your function to check if you can connect to Application Insights successfully.

[image]

Reference:

[Monitor Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd)

**Update2:**
Try to use the query as below. `HttpTrigger1` is the function name.

```
traces 
| where operation_Name == "HttpTrigger1"
| where timestamp > ago(24h) 
| limit 20
```

[image]

Besides, restarting means restart the function app.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the log is found under **Monitor** thank you. But the **Logs** only shows "Connecting to Application Insights...". By "restarting" do you mean just clicking the "Run" button again? And could you please explain the query text for me? Please see the updated question.